# Need to repromt the user in case he input digits and not letters

Tags: c, input

I am trying to  make a program that will  ask a user to enter his name.  If he gives number instead I want the program to repromt user  until  he inputs characters as name.

it should look something like this :

```
char name[50];
printf("What is your name? ");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("Hello there, %s\n", name);
```

In the above  all is good BUT it does not recognize when you input number digits. I want to repromt the user in the case he inputs numbers and accept only  letters

I have made the following code but obviously is not working. I would really  appreciate your help. Just remember ..keep  it simple!

```
int main()
{
  char name[50];

  int age, agenext, id, idnext = 0;

  //PROMT USER  TO INPUT NAME

  printf("\nPlease enter your name:\n");
  scanf("%s", &name);

      while (isdigit(name))

      {
        printf("wrong input try again");

      }
printf("Your name is %s ",name);
return 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I have added the C tag.  If this is not correct, please edit it.  Also, you should edit your question to state spefically what your problem is.  Is the problem that you are trying to apply `isdigit` to all the elements of `name`?  Also, note that if you fixed the condition, your `while` loop will iterate forever since there is no opportunity to re-enter `name`

Comment: also  i am supposed to  be in the beginning in C yet  so  the solution must  be simple like that:                                                                                           char name[50]
...
printf("What is your name? ");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("Hello there, %s\n", name);

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions:  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) place a leading space in the format string to consume any leading white space.  3) when using the '%s' format specifier, always use a 'max length modifier that is one less than the the input buffer length to avoid the user overflowing the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour that can lead to a seg fault event.  Note: 1 less because with '%s', `scanf()` always append a NUL byte.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  never use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently. indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each level of indenting as that is visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code has a forever loop (the while() loop) and is checking the address of the array `name[]` rather than the individual characters.

Comment: the posted code is missing the final closing brace '}' and is missing the needed `#include <stdio.h>` statement

Answer (score 1):

Consider using fgets to read the input. Loop through each character of name and see if it is a digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( )
{
    char name[50];
    int valid = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t each = 0;

    do {
        valid = 1;
        printf ( "Please enter your name\n");
        fgets ( name, sizeof ( name), stdin);//read a line
        name[strcspn ( name, "\n")] = '\0';//optional removal of newline
        len = strlen ( name);
        for ( each = 0; each < len; each++) {//loop through each character
            if ( ( isdigit ( name[each]))) {//found a digit
                valid = 0;
                printf ( "Do not use digits\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( !valid);
    printf ( "Your name is %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are other ways to terminate a input string besides a newline, so should check for the presence of a newline `char newline = strstr( name, "\n");`   then check `newline` to see if a newline was found.  `if( newline ) { newline = '\0'; }`

Comment: Thanks, I was under the mistaken impression that it returned 0 when the `needle` was not found

Answer (score 1):

Only slightly modified your code:

```
int has_digits(char * str)
{
    for (; *str; str++)
    {
        if (isdigit(*str))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char name[50];

    //PROMT USER  TO INPUT NAME

    printf("\nPlease enter your name:\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    while (has_digits(name))
    {
        printf("wrong input try again\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
    }
    printf("Your name is %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very  much  . Could you  explain  why  is wrong  the way  i used iisdigit in mine?

Comment: `isdigit` is used to check individual characters, so you have to loop through each of the characters in the string and call the function to see if any of them is a digit. You should also look into the issues commented under your original question, such as error checking of scanf etc.